# How to add labels to an existing Google Dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am using the Java GAPI client to work with Google Cloud Dataflow (v1b3-rev197-1.22.0). I am running a pipeline from template and the method for doing that (`com.google.api.services.dataflow.Dataflow.Projects.Templates#create`) does not allow me to set labels for the job. However I get the `Job` object back when I execute the pipeline, so I updated the labels and tried to call `com.google.api.services.dataflow.Dataflow.Projects.Jobs#update` to persist that information in Dataflow. But the labels do not get updated.

I also tried updating labels on finished jobs (which I also need to do), which didn't work either, so I thought it's because the job is in a terminal state. But updating labels seems to do nothing regardless of the state.

The documentation does not say anything about labels not being mutable on running or terminated pipelines, so I would expect things to work. Am I doing something wrong and if not what is the rationale behing the decision no to allow label updates? (And how are template users supposed to set the initial label set when executing the template?)

Background: I want to mark terminated pipelines that have been "processed", i.e. those that our automated infrastructure already sent notification about to appropriate places. Labels seemed as a good approach that would shield me from having to use some kind of local persitence to track stuff (big complexity jump). Any suggestions on how to approach this if labels are not the right tool? Sadly, Stackdriver cannot monitor finished pipelines, only failed ones. And sending a notification from within the pipeline code doesn't seem as a good idea to me (wrong?).

Comment: Labels on Dataflow Jobs don't have quite the flexibility as you may have seem on GCE instances, for example.  Could you clarify what you mean by "Stackdriver cannot monitor finished pipelines"?  Also, could you help me understand your use case a bit better?  Are you trying to record the state of activity happening outside of your pipeline?

Comment: @Andrea By "Stackdriver cannot monitor finished pipelines" I mean that you cannot have an alert on a pipeline finishing successfully, only on failure. That is what I understand from exploring the Stackdriver UI and trying to setup alerts. It's understandable, I guess. After all, the alert system in Stackdriver is meant to help with troubleshooting stuff...

Comment: What I am trying to do is to monitor pipelines and when a pipeline finishes successfully I want to notify other parts of my system and tell them that the data is ready and where it is. I continuously monitor the states of running pipelines (because Dataflow itself does not support any kind of notification system) and when a pipeline finishes I send a Pub/Sub message. And I want to know which pipelines I already "processed" without having to have some local persistence, if possible. So I wanted to "flag" them using labels.

Comment: It's an interesting idea to have an "is_done" metric in addition to an "is_failed" metric.  I'll look into that.  In the meantime, every job has an "elapsed time" value published about every 30 secs to a minute.  You should be able to set up an alert on the absence on that metric for a few minutes to notify you that a job is complete.  Would that meet your needs?

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll look into that, thanks! Too bad Satackdriver cannot send alert notifications via Pub/Sub :(